# The number of different ordered trees with 3 nodes labeled Y, Y, Z are?

Tags: tree

The number of different ordered trees with 3 nodes labelled Y, Y, Z are ?
please can anyone explain me this i have tried different approaches but nothing is matching my answer..

Comment: Any tree, or binary tree?

Comment: Hello... are you there?

Answer (score 0):

First count the number of shapes a tree with 3 nodes can have. Its height can be either 2 or 3 (since a tree of height 1 has 1 node, and a tree of height 4 needs at least 4 nodes).

There is only one shape for a tree with three nodes of height two:

```
     *
   /   \
  *     *
```

When the height is three, then the tree is really a chain:

```
     * 
    /
   *      
  /
 *
```

In case this question is about *binary* trees with ordered children (left/right), then there are four options for a tree of height three:

```
     *      *       *      *
    /      /         \      \
   *      *           *      *
  /        \         /        \
 *          *       *          *
```

Similar analysis can be done for possible 3-ary trees, 4-ary trees, etc.

So for *any* tree with *unordered* children, there are only two shapes. For binary trees with *ordered* children, there are five shapes. For *any* tree with *ordered* children, there are an infinite number of shapes.

For each shape you can consider 6 different labellings: 3 nodes can get the label X, 2 of the others can get the label Y, and the remaining one gets label Z.

3 * 2 * 1 = 6.

So the answer for binary trees with ordered children is: 5 shapes * 6 labellings = 30 trees.